# Optimize this query without using not exist repeatably, is there a better way to write this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example I have three table where say DataTable1, DataTable2 and DataTable3
and need to filter it from DataRange table, every time I have used NOT exist as shown below,
Is there a better way to write this.

Temp table to hold some daterange which is used for fiter:

```
Declare @DateRangeTable as Table(
    StartDate datetime,
    EndDate datetime
)
```

Some temp table which will hold data on which we need to apply date range filter

```
INSERT INTO @DateRangeTable values
('07/01/2020','07/04/2020'),
('07/06/2020','07/08/2020');

/*Table 1 which will hold some data*/
Declare @DataTable1 as Table(
    Id numeric,
    Date datetime
)

INSERT INTO @DataTable1 values
(1,'07/09/2020'),
(2,'07/06/2020');


Declare @DataTable2 as Table(
    Id numeric,
    Date datetime
)
INSERT INTO @DataTable2 values
(1,'07/10/2020'),
(2,'07/06/2020');


Declare @DataTable3 as Table(
    Id numeric,
    Date datetime
)
INSERT INTO @DataTable3 values
(1,'07/11/2020'),
(2,'07/06/2020');
```

Now I want to filter data based on DateRange table, here I need some optimized way so that i don't have to use not exists mutiple times, In real senario, I have mutiple tables where I have to filter based on the daterange table.

```
Select * from @DataTable1
where NOT EXISTS(
    Select 1 from @DateRangeTable
    where [Date] between StartDate and EndDate
)

Select * from @DataTable2
where NOT EXISTS(
    Select 1 from @DateRangeTable
    where [Date] between StartDate and EndDate
)

Select * from @DataTable3
where NOT EXISTS(
    Select 1 from @DateRangeTable
    where [Date] between StartDate and EndDate
)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this optimization? Legibility, performance, maintainability?

Comment: I have lot of data so, Performance of the query

Comment: Youare not using it multiple times. You are using it once per query. I know it feels like you are copy pasting code, but the `[Date] ` column is actually 3 different columns (`@DataTable1.Date`; `@DataTable2.Date` ; `@DataTable3.Date`). The  query looks fine to me.

Comment: Yes, so is there a better way to write this ?

Comment: if you are asking regarding performance we need to see the execution plan.

Comment: typo: First datevalue in @DataTable2 has 3 figures together

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `NOT EXISTS` you could join the date range table:

```
SELECT dt.* 
FROM @DataTable1 dt
    LEFT JOIN @DateRangeTable dr ON dt.[Date] BETWEEN dr.StartDate and dr.EndDate
WHERE dr.StartDate IS NULL
```

It may perform better on large tables but you would have to compare the execution plans and make sure you have indexes on the date columns.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the same query... but if you can change table structure I would try to improve performance adding two columns to specify the month as an integer (I suppose is the first couple of figures).

Obviously you have to test with your data and compare the timings.

```
Declare @DateRangeTable as Table(
    StartDate datetime,
    EndDate datetime,
    StartMonth tinyint,
    EndMonth tinyint
)

INSERT INTO @DateRangeTable values
('07/01/2020','07/04/2020', 7, 7),
('07/06/2020','07/08/2020', 7, 7),
('07/25/2020','08/02/2020', 7, 8);    // (another record with different months)
```

Now your queries can use the new column to try to reduce comparisons (is a tinyint, sql server can partition records if you define a secondary index for StartMonth and EndMonth):

```
Select * from @DataTable1
where NOT EXISTS(
    Select 1 from @DateRangeTable
    where (DATEPART('month', [Date]) between StartMonth and EndMonth)
    and ([Date] between StartDate and EndDate)
)
```